# How to control cache in Nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, caching, nestjs

I read the doc of nestjs recently, and learned something from it.

But I found something that puzzled me.

In [Techniques/Caching](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching), the doc shows me to use a decorator like `@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)` on a controller to cache its response (default track by route).

I wrote a testcase and found it's useful. But I didn't find any explanation to show how to clean the cache. That means I have to wait for the cache to expire.

In my opinion, a cache store must provide an API to clear the cache by key, so that it can update the cache when data changes (by explicitly calling a clear API).

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to remove cache from backend?

Comment: @JanithKasun I want to know how to remove cache from backend, by the Caching module designed in [Nestjs](https://github.com/nestjs/nest)

Answer (score 6):

You can inject the underlying `cache-manager` instance with `@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER)`. On the `cache-manager` instance you can then call the method `del(key, cb)` to clear the cache for a specified key, see the [docs](https://github.com/BryanDonovan/node-cache-manager#overview).

#### Example

```
counter = 0;
constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager) {}

// The first call increments to one, the preceding calls will be answered by the cache
// without incrementing the counter. Only after you clear the cache by calling /reset
// the counter will be incremented once again.
@Get()
@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
incrementCounter() {
  this.counter++;
  return this.counter;
}

// Call this endpoint to reset the cache for the route '/'
@Get('reset')
resetCache() {
  const routeToClear = '/';
  this.cacheManager.del(routeToClear, () => console.log('clear done'));
}
```

[image: Edit nest-clear-cache]

Comment: Hi @kim-kern . Thanks for the answer. I would like to know what is the data type of `cacheManager` variable (`@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager`)

Comment: @SohelAhmedM Try `npm install --save-dev @types/cache-manager`

Comment: I have added a simple minimal nestjs-redis-cache example - https://gist.github.com/SOHELAHMED7/f7396fb7711aad9538e149e1b811b53c

Comment: Is there a way we can enable and disable entire caching feature via a flag(true/false) in config

Comment: @Vallie It's hard to answer your question without seeing more details. When is the flag set? Statically on server start or dynamically? How is it set? ... Please open a new question and include a code example that describes your use case. :-)

Comment: Posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942382/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-caching-in-nest-js

Answer (score 1):

You could also use another approach, you could use [utils-decorators](https://github.com/vlio20/utils-decorators#memoizeasync--method) lib (`npm install --save utils-decorators`) and take advantage of the AsyncMemoize decorator. Then you only need to add a decorator to you controller function:

```
import {memoizeAsync} from 'utils-decorators';

const cache = new Map();

class Controller {


 @Get()
 @memoizeAsync({cache: cache})
 incrementCounter() {
  this.counter++;

  return this.counter;
 }

 @Get('reset')
 resetCache() {
   // do whatever you want with the cache map.
 }
}
```