# How to cache data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, caching, nestjs

I create two functions, first- `Get` to get data by id from database and cacheing it, and second - `POST` to update data in database. And the problem is in this, that i must cache after get and after update.

Can someone tell me how do this?

I use NestJS, and documentation tells that, cache is working only on `GET` controller.
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching

my code:

service:

```
    async getUser(userID: number): Promise<UserEntity> {
        const user = await this.conn.getRepository(UserEntity).findOne(userID);

        return user;
    }

    
    async updateUser(userID: number, dto: UserEntityDto): Promise<ResultDTO> {
        const user = await this.conn.getRepository(UserEntity).findOne(configId);
        

       //all logic
    }
```

controller:

```
@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
export class UserControleer{
    constructor(
        private readonly userService: UserService
    ){}

    @Get('/:userID')
    @CacheKey('custom_key')
    @CacheTTL(20)
    async getUser(
        @Param('userID') userID: number
    ): Promise<UserEntity> {
        return await this.userService.getUser(userID);
    }

    @Post('/:userID')
    async updateUser(
        @Param('userID') userID: number,
        @Body() dto: UserDTO
    ): Promise<ResultDTO> {
        return await this.userService.updateUser(userID, dto);
    }
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You would probably want to [invalidate the cache entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156379/how-to-control-cache-in-nestjs) so it gets re-cached on the next call or update the cached entry after the user is modified.

**Explanation**
Caching with annotations usually works as a proxy that intercepts the method call.

The proxy looks for an entry in the configured cache. The match is usually based on the method signature and the method arguments. If a match was found, the cached result will be returned.

It's important for us to understand, that underlaying method is not getting called when a match was found. That's the reason why we wouldn't wan't to cache an update method, since the arguments probably change often and the update should be executed at all times.

**Options**
There are lots of options for your use-case, here are two:

- invalidate the cache entry when updating the data; re-cache the data on the next call
- update the cached data after the update operation

**Further infos**
You can find more information on managing the cache in this Stack Overflow question:
[How to control cache in Nestjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156379/how-to-control-cache-in-nestjs)