# How can I enable or disable caching in nest js?

Tags: nestjs

Let us say we would want to disable cache when running on dev server and enable caching mechanism on prod server instead of adding and removing the CacheInterceptor interceptor. How would we go about it?

```
@Get()
@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
getData()
  return "here is your data";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this task using a simple solution:

```
import { Module, CacheModule } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
    imports: [
        CacheModule.registerAsync({
            // just return undefined instead of cache store config
            useFactory: async () => !IS_DEV && myCacheStoreConfig,
        }),
    ],
    ...
})
```

Comment: Not working for me, I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'store')`

Comment: @Pleymor it seems there is a problem in Your cache config. Cache config has the property `store` and (I suppose) it is invalid.